# Calling a Python method from one class to another

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class A: 
    def getTotal(self)
        self.__total = 0
        for each in self.__hand:
            if each.getValue() == 1 and self.__total > 10:
                self.__total += 1
            elif each.getValue() == 1 and self.__total <10:
                self.__total += 11
            elif each.getValue() != 1:
                self.__total += each.getValue()
        return self.__total

class B: 
    def getTotal(self):
        return A.getTotal()
```

This isn't working for me. How can I get class A to return a total when called from class B's method

Comment: `A` is a *class*, not an instance. There is no `self` to bind to. Did you mean for `B` to be a **subclass** of `A` perhaps?

Comment: If that means that I can call class A's method from class B's method, then maybe yea.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: that'll only work if `B` inherits from `A`.

Comment: You're also missing a little bit of syntax here. `def getTotal(self):` and the indent on `return self.__total` is wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then he can create an A instance.

Comment: @Torched90: so, is `B` a specialised form of `A`? You don't do anything more in `B.getTotal()`; you could just do `class B(A): pass` and be done with it; you can then use `B.getTotal()` because it'll be inherited.

Comment: @Torched90: note that you don't need to make `__total` an attribute of `self` at all; it is just a local. Remove the `self.`, rename `__total` to `total` and it'll be a local.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters The B class has other methods in it. Sorry for not writing them.

Comment: @Torched90: That's okay, but it is unclear why you have a `class B` at all. You may have oversimplified here. I think `A` is a card player (hand of cards) class. Is `B` another card player but more specialised (for a specific game type perhaps)? Or is `B` a game with multiple players? What should `B.getTotal()` *do* in your program?

Comment: So A is the Hand class, it creates a hand (list of card objects from another class), and B is a Player class, so B.getTotal() should return the total value of a players hand. The A class also has a getTotal() because it returns the total of a hand, but B's getTotal() returns the total of the players hand

Comment: @Torched90: so how is the hand associated with the player? is there a `self.hand`?

Comment: Yea, there is a self.hand in both classes though. I'm not the one to come up with the skeleton, I'm just supposed to fill in the methods, but it doesn't make sense to me as to why we need to have getTotal method twice and self.hand twice.

Comment: @Torched90: `Hand.__hand` should be renamed to `Hand.__cards` then, because it is just the list of cards the current hand holds.

Comment: Okay, then how would I call the getTotal from A using B's getTotal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just call `A.getTotal()` because it is an *unbound method*; there is nothing to bind `self` to as you didn't give it an instance of `A`, where you'd have state. You need to call it on an *instance* of `A`. We just need to find one first.

From the comments I understand `B` to the the player, and `A` is a hand of cards for that player. Presumably in a game a player can play end up with more hands as multiple rounds are played.

In that case you'd have a reference from the player to the hand, like `self.hand`. That'd be an instance of `A` and you can call `getTotal()` on *that* instead:

```
class B:
    def getTotal(self):
        return self.hand.getTotal()
```

It may be confusing here that `A` also has a `__hand` attribute; that's perhaps not the best name for that attribute, as it is the list of cards for the current hand. It could perhaps better be named `__cards` in that case.

`B.getTotal()` is not strictly needed; you could also just use `instance_of_B.hand.getTotal()`, e.g. reach right into the instance attributes and call `getTotal()` directly on the hand. But that'd perhaps reveal too much about how the class handles hands, and perhaps you want to handle different cases, like return `0` if there is the possibility that at some points in the program is no hand at all.

And another thing: `__total` in `A.getTotal()` is a local variable; you don't need to use an attribute on `self` there. Remove the `self.` prefix, and just name it `total`:

```
def getTotal(self)
    total = 0
    for each in self.__hand:
        if each.getValue() == 1:
            if total > 10:
                total += 1
            else:
                total += 11
        else:
            total += each.getValue()
    return total
```

I simplified the function logic a little too.

Comment: I have this now, but it is giving me the error: 'list' object has no attribute getTotal

Comment: @Torched90: so is `self.hand` a list perhaps?

Comment: Yea, its a list of card objects.

Comment: @Torched90: it is on the `A` class, yes, but not the player class (class `B`), is it?

Comment: @Torched90: or have you got multiple hands on class `B`? Then what should the total be, the sum of all the hands?

Comment: In both A and B there is only one hand. There is self.__hand on both A and B. The total should be the sum of the card's values.

Comment: @Torched90: But your error shows that `B.__hand` is a list. It probably should not be a list however.

Comment: @Torched90: `A` is the `Hand` class, so `B.__hand` should be **one** instance of that class. But apparently you have a whole list of those instead.

Comment: So how would I create a Hand object, and not a list?

Comment: Okay, I finally figured out my problem. It was a simple error in my testing strategy. Thank you so very much for all your help. I really appreciated it.